# Loop and array issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Ok, I have a literal arrays where there are some images in it. I have an empty DIV where a FOR LOOP will be carried out to display all the images in the array in the div.

```
var icons = [
    '<img src="images/1.png" width="30" height="30"/>',
    '<img src="images/2.png" width="30" height="30"/>',
    '<img src="images/3.png" width="30" height="30"/>'
    ];

    var lol = document.getElementById("div");

    for (var i=0; i<icons.length; i++) {
            lol.innerHTML = icons[i] ;
        }
```

The issue is only the last image is displayed not all...

Comment: Better use DOM manipulation rather than `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are overwriting the previous image with the current one. If you want to append/concat all images, use `+=`:

```
lol.innerHTML += icons[i];
```

A better way to handle this would be to use DOM handling:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", icons[i]);

lol.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: i prefer the += lol.innerHTML.... as if someone wants to add an image, just just it in the array...

Comment: That works with the DOM handling to. Just put my last snippet inside your for-loop.

Comment: @user1780468 Yeah, that works, but `innerHTML` is just as **evil** as `document.write`. It can easily break the DOM if careless. That's why I prefer DOM manipulation with the use of `document.createElement`and `document.createTextNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you do

```
lol.innerHTML = icons[i];
```

you're *replacing* the inner HTML of the div with `icons[i]`. Concatenate all your icon elements, and then set the inner HTML of the div with the result of the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

your code is overwrite the innerHTML you can append the innerHTML

try this

```
lol.innerHTML += icons[i];
```

this above code is append the innerHTML

or in jquery you can use append function

```
$('#div').append(icons[i]);
```